# Force https for single directory on my server with nginx config

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, nginx-location

I am trying to force SSL for a single subdirectory on my server by placing a rewrite rule in my nginx config file.

So, for example, when a user goes to example.com/billing or example.com/billing/user they are taken to https://example.com/billing or https://example.com/billing/user.

I have an SSL certificate installed etc. Here is a rule in my server block for nginx:

```
#billing location
location /billing/ {
    if (!-e $request_filename){
        rewrite ^/billing/(.*)$ /billing/index.php?request=$1 last;
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can modify this rule to include forcing https?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have two server blocks one for http and other of http SSL connection; in your http server block adding redirect to https inside `/billing/` location block will solve the issue.

```
server {
 listen 80;
 location /billing/ {
   # 301 for permanent redirect
   return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
 }
}
```